# Android Device and Bluetooth connection Issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a person who is developing an Android application using BLE.

In order to communicate with the device(peripheral) through BLE communication( GATT )

Galaxy Note 9, a terminal that was used for testing, suddenly started to not connect to GATT.

So I tested it with the Galaxy Tab (sm-t510) and it works fine. I build it on the same code, but I wonder why the Note 9 gets dirty as soon as it is connected to GATT and breaks really immediately.

In contrast, the tabs are doing very well.

I searched on the wiki, the tab is bluetooth 5.0 and the Galaxy Note 9 is bluetooth 5.0 + LE.

The device(peripheral) identifies the Bluetooth 4.1 device.

If you have any doubts about it, please help me

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy was introduced with the Bluetooth specification 4.0. When it comes to Smartphones and tablets, all modern devices using Bluetooth 4.0 and above are equipped with a multi purpose chip allowing connections via Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy. This means that your Galaxy Tab can also use BLE, even if it does not say so on the wiki

Comment: I have a three devices (tablet, Phone, peripheral device), last one is my only peripheral mode and other is client. The problem is why Only phone cant connect with peripheral device ?

Comment: Could you maybe add some code and your error message/log to your question?

Comment: There no exception and any other error just Phone automatically disconnected with peripheral device...Phone makes it unpaired, also i cant find in Android basic Setting Bluetooth connected list too

Comment: Just for your information: You don't need to connect or pair a device using the settings of your phones operating system if using BLE. This is done directly through your app. It is normal to not find a BLE device in said settings

Comment: How about this issue. If my Gatt automatic disconnection was be affected by Samsung S pen. How i solve this problem. I dont want to be affected by other autoconnect device such as like Airpods or S-Pen